# Using linq to determine if inner property of type Object has car number which equals input

Tags: c#, linq

Hello i am trying to use linq to solve the following problem.

A **simplified** example :

```
public class Car 
{    
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public object Extension { get; set; }
}

public class CarExtension
{
    public string SpecialNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I need to be able to use linq to query Car object and determine if `SpecialNumber` equals my input.
The problem is that i dont have the `CarExtension` class.
I only got `"object"` type.

So i can't use linq like this:

```
var item = cars.Where(x => x.Extension.SpecialNumber == input);
```

Edit : Important detail i should have mentioned is  - I am not aware of the CarExtension type in run time.

The ideal solution will be to not have `CarExtension` in the code. 
So i will be able to use this function later on even if it is going to be for a different extension type which also going to have a `SpecialNumber` property.

P.S. I am using it to query mongodb. It cant be a specific type because the extension type has to support all sort of structures and i cant change this design because there were some reasons behind it (for the real data structure).

Comment: How much of this design can you change? And is this using LINQ to Objects, or are you trying to use EF or something similar?

Comment: Why is it `Object` when it's always a `CarExtension`? If it has to be, why you can't simply cast it to `CarExtension`?

Comment: How did you end up with such class definition? May you can correct that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. The preferred approach would be to change the class design. I don't see any reason for using `object` when you know that the value would be a `CarExtension` instance, except for the possible fact that this is a big project that you can't change.
2. If you can't change the design, you could check the type of the object in the query:

   ```
   var item = cars
       .Where(x => x.Extension is CarExtension
                && ((CarExtension)x.Extension).SpecialNumber == input);
   ```

   With C# 7 (Visual Studio 2017 required for this), that could be rewritten using Pattern Matching:

   ```
   var item = cars
       .Where(x => x.Extension is CarExtension carExtension
                && carExtension.SpecialNumber == input);
   ```

Comment: Note that with C# 7 pattern matching, the second option can be written as `x => x.Extension is CarExtension ce && ce.SpecialNumber == input`. With C# 8 it'll be even simpler with property patterns :)

Comment: @DaisyShipton Yeah, nice catch, thanks. Not a lot of people is aware or can use C# 7 though

Comment: if i could use dynamic instead of CarExtension it would have been nice...
This solution might work for me for now but it is going to be very specific... and if at some point i will need 2 different extensions to support it i will be forced to restructure the data classes.

Comment: @Ivgi There's nothing preventing the use of `dynamic` here, but I wouldn't recommend it. c# is type safe for a reason

Comment: I understand that but this case seem kinda fitting for me ( for now ),
but in either case it seems that linq continues to complain about it.
"an expression tree may not contain a dynamic expression"

Answer (score 0):

you should do this ,as you are already aware that extension is of type `CarExtension`

```
var item = cars.Where(x => (x.Extension as CarExtension)?.SpecialNumber == input);
```

Comment: @Rahul - i wrote in my answer it going to be of type CarExtension ..right ? then how come it will come null

Comment: @Rahul - if i am already aware then why should i do `is ` then do `as` ....

Answer (score 0):

You can cast object Extension to CarExtension

```
            List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
            Car r = new Car() { Number = "1", Extension = new CarExtension() { SpecialNumber = "5" } };
            cars.Add(r);
            var l = cars.Where(x => ((CarExtension)x.Extension).SpecialNumber == "5").ToList();
```